# on pressing default cancel icon[x] of called JFrame layout class, calling layout class gets cancelled too

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Class1 which is a NewJFrame Form and is also a calling class to class2, NewJFrame3 has a Jbutton component, jButton1, for which method actionPerformed has been over-ridden. I call the object with a thread. On calling, Class2, NewJFrame3, a new frame pops up. Problem is when I press the default cross of called class, NewJFrame3, button [X], both screens gets cancelled. I was not using threads before and was calling the layout method for JFrame3 with just object, but it had this problem, so i used thread but it wouldnt work.

Code of calling class (Layout is fine for this and on clicking its button JButton1, class NewJframe3’s layout pops up) :

```
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame implements ActionListener
{
public NewJFrame() 
{
    initComponents();
        jButton1.addActionListener(this);
}

private void initComponents() 
{
//layout code for JFrame1 – gives the desired layout/output
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
    If(some_condition)
        {
            NewJFrame3 obj2 = new NewJFrame3();    
                Thread th1 = new Thread(obj2, "thread1");
                th1.start();
                }
    }
 public static void main(String args[]) 
{
           java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
                   {
                        public void run() 
                               {
                                    new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);             

                               }
                   });
}//Main ends
}//Calling Class NewJFrame1 ends
```

Code for called class(same package) :

```
public class NewJFrame3 extends javax.swing.JFrame implements Runnable
{
               public void run() 
                  {
                       // System.out.println("Inside Run");
                           this.test();
                           this.setVisible(true);
                  }

             protected void test()
                 {
                        //layout code for JFrame3 – gives the desired layout/output
                 }

        PSVM()
          {
//Main method code not relevant here, since layout function is called from run() which gets called on starting thread for this class.
           }

} //Called Class NewJFrame3 end
```

Thanks a ton for your time!

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Comment: Thankyou much for all replies and suggestion.

- Apparently, i did not want to use another JFrame, because all i really need is a dialog window.
- Im using NetBeans IDE, so for creating a new container it gives me an option for JFrame form or JPanel form. Dialog needs some container, and then when i try to add Dialog to the main Frame COntainer (auto-generated in JFrame form), it does not allow that. So i took a longer route and created a label in the frame. 
- So there is just 1 frame which calls another frame, and there arent any internal frames.
- Please correct me where i am wrong.
Fraggy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- you have to set for [defaultCloseOperation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultCloseOperation-int-), set to `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` in this case, last of [JFrames](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html) to terminating an Current JVM
- your current issue is default value `HIDE_ON_CLOSE`, then current JVM is still running, consume and increase RAM in PC
- use [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) or [JDialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) with parent, and/or `setModal`/ `ModalityTypes` instead of two `JFrames`

Comment: on a side note,[ive searched] why doesnt default JFrame of created JFrame form(in Netbeans IDE) allow a JDialog to be added to it?(when you right click to add or drag to add), but if you manipulate code for that, t allows.. Any clues? Thankyou much, Fraggy